# FXML Style Not Applied To Dynamically Added TreeView TreeItem's

Tags: css, javafx, fxml

I am trying to apply css styles to A `TreeView` `TreeItem` but for some reason the item isn't picking up, and applying the style. Here is a snippet of the `fxml` file. As you can see the `TreeView` doesn't have any items, that is because I am adding them at a later time.

```
<AnchorPane styleClass="/media/css/TreeItem.css" id="AnchorPane" fx:id="main" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="db.manager.MainController">
    <children>
        <AnchorPane>
            <children>
                <TreeView editable="true" showRoot="false" />
            </children>
        </AnchorPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I then have the following css in the file css file mentioned in the above `fxml`:

```
.tree-cell{
    -fx-indent: 100;
    -fx-underline: true;
    -fx-background-image: url("/media/images/database.png");
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I am not getting any errors, so I know that the file is loading, but the style aren't getting applied to the newly added `TreeItem`'s and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
<AnchorPane stylesheets="/media/css/TreeItem.css" ... >
```

not

```
<AnchorPane styleClass="/media/css/TreeItem.css" ... >
```